# Animation delay on page load

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying to create a delay for an image to load. I have the following, but I really want it to delay loading for 10 seconds, not just fade in. How can I modify this to get a delay before loading?

```css
.image {
  animation: fadeinLoad 10s;
}

@keyframes fadeinLoad {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/od9bJ.png" />
```

Comment: That edit looks like it should be a comment instead. You should see an add comment link under Josh's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to give the `.image` class `opacity: 0` so it loads hidden. Then, delay the animation:

```
animation: fadeinLoad 1s 5s forwards;
```

The second time of `5s` specifies a wait to activate time of 5 seconds. The `forwards` property pauses the animation at 100%.

The shorthand above is the same as this:

```
animation-name: fadeinLoad; 
animation-duration: 1s; 
animation-delay: 5s; 
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

[Read more on CSS animation over on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation).

### Example

Count to five :)

```css
.image {
  animation: fadeinLoad 1s 5s forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes fadeinLoad {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Count to 5!</h1>

<img class="image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/od9bJ.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this much simpler than keyframe animations.

Change your code to something like this:

```
#topHeader .image {
  transition-delay: 10s;
  transition: opacity 1s; 
  opacity: 0;
}
#topHeader .image.YOUR-FIRING-CLASSNAME-HERE {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Plus, the days of needing to prefix every CSS3 property are pretty much over.  You don't need `-o-`, `-ms-`, etc. etc.

Save for keyframes, as those apparently don't have large-scale standardized support just yet.